# Patched Rust binary in Ghidra on MacOS (AARCH64) results in process killed

Tags: macos, rust, reverse-engineering, arm64, ghidra

I've written a simple Rust program to learn reverse engineering on with a simple loop that breaks when you enter the "correct" password, this is the program:

```
use std::io;
fn main() {
    println!("Enter password:");
    let mut pass = String::new();
    loop {
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut pass)
            .expect("Failed to read line");

        match pass.as_str().trim() {
            "reddit" => break,
            _ => println!("Wrong password"),
        }
    }
    println!("You've guessed it!");
}
```

I've located the code in Ghidra responsible for the jump i.e.:

```
                     LAB_100002ce4                         XREF[1]:     100002ce0(j)  
       100002ce4 e8 0f 40 b9     ldr        w8,[sp, #local_124]
       100002ce8 28 01 00 37     tbnz       w8,#0x0,LAB_100002d0c
       100002cec 0f 00 00 14     b          LAB_100002d28
```

I looked up the `tbnz` instruction in ARM64 instruction set manual and and based on that "patched the instruction" in the following way:

```
tbnz       w8,#0x0,LAB_100002d0c --> tbnz       w8,#0x1,LAB_100002d0c
```

The decompiler window showed exactly what I would expect:

```
if ((uVar1 & 1) != 0) break; --> if ((uVar1 >> 1 & 1) != 0) break;
```

I exported the binary in two ways:

- Original file or
- Raw bytes

I've then `chmod +x` the resulting binaries and try to run them. It gets killed (SIGKILL (9)).

What I've tried:

- I've found out about `xattributes` and so I checked if they are "quarantined" and they weren't. As a matter of fact they didn't have any `xattributes`.
- I've tried switching the branch `b` labels instead but to no avail
- To rule out these code changes I've tried to just open up the binary and then without any change save it as raw bytes. Again it wouldn't run.

Did anyone encounter a similar problem and could help? I've attached the changes as well just in case the issue might be two fold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've resolved the issue.

For anyone who will encounter a similar problem it's due to an invalid certificate and the binary needs to be signed again.

To do this without an Apple Developer ID you need to:

```
Open 'Keychain Access' -> (Toolbar) Keychain Access -> Certificate Assistant -> Create a Certificate
```

And create a code signing certificate.

Then to codesign the binary:

```
codesign -fs name-of-certificate path/to/binary-to-be-signed
```